# Changing an boolean if the checkbox is clicked

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello I working on an `Angular` project and have an [list of elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0lA5.png) that can be checked.

My business logic is that:

```
stateChange(event: any, illRecipe: Attendance){

    var state: State = {
        is_checked: event.checked,
        attandance: illRecipe
    };

    this.checkboxValues.push(state);

    console.log(this.checkboxValues);

   
}
```

every time the checkbox is clicked this function fires and pushes the value to the array.
My question is: How can I update the objects in the array? or is there a way to better solution to update this object ? I know that the `state` updates but in the array I get a new element.

[console.log(this.checkboxValues)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4rIx.png)

**UPDATE**

I'm now trying this:

```
stateChange(event: any, illRecipe: Attendance){

    var state: State = {
        is_checked: event.checked,
        attandance: illRecipe
    };

    console.log(state);

        this.checkboxValues.push(state);
        //push the object into array

        var isSameId = this.checkboxValues.filter( value => value.attandance.id == state.attandance.id)
        // filter to find checkboxes that are clicked multiple times

        if(isSameId.length >= 2){
            this.checkboxValues.forEach((checkBoxValue, checkboxIndex) =>{
                isSameId.forEach((sameValue, sameIndex) =>{
                    if(sameValue.attandance.id == checkBoxValue.attandance.id && isSameId.length > 1){
                        this.checkboxValues.splice(checkboxIndex, 1)
                    }
                })
            })
        }
        //trying to sort out the older entries with the same id
   
    console.log("checkboxValues",this.checkboxValues);
}
```

my goal is it to get rid of duplicates in the `checkboxValues` array. I'm getting pretty close but some where is a small hick up. If I press one checkbox three time then another and then the already pressed again it switches an in the array is the unchecked object and the one pressed disappears.

frontend:

```
 <div *ngFor="let ill of illAttendances">
                <div *ngIf="!ill.is_file_uploaded" class="box">
                    <div class="p-grid">
                        <div class="p-col-1">
                            <p-checkbox (onChange)="stateChange($event, ill)"></p-checkbox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="p-col">
                            <div *ngIf="ill.start != undefined && ill.end != undefined">
                                {{ ill.absence_type | titlecase }} von <b>{{ ill.start | date:'d MMMM y' }}</b> bis
                                <b>{{ ill.end | date:'d MMMM y' }}</b>
                            </div>

                            <div *ngIf="ill.one_day != null">
                                {{ ill.absence_type | titlecase }} am <b>{{ ill.one_day | date:'d MMMM y' }}</b>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <br>
            </div>
```

Comment: I can't really seem to follow what you're trying to achieve.
You want to check several items in a list and then upload one image referencing all checked list items?

Also please try to minimize your example and try to explain in more detail what your task / problem is.

Comment: I updated my question can you now understand it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell without saying you html but I think you can use a Array of `State` (your state object lets call it `stateList`) and bind the checkbox the item of that array. This way your `stateList` will keep the checked state of the related `Attendance` and you don't need to keep a separate list or handle the `stateChange` event.

if you can upload your view code for the checkboxes we can take another look.

if you can replicate the below approach using your own data type (and structure) I think it better as you have 2 different list for one job.

in your comp.ts file init the array with `Attendance`

```
export class AppComponent {
  stateList = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    // use your own attandence e.g. attandence: yourAttandenceObj
    this.stateList.push({ is_checked: false, attandence: { name: 'Att1' /*and other data*/ } });
    this.stateList.push({ is_checked: false, attandence: { name: 'Att2' } });
    this.stateList.push({ is_checked: false, attandence: { name: 'Att3' } });
  }
}
```

and in your html

```
  <div *ngFor="let state of stateList">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="state.is_checked"/>
      {{state.attandence.name}}
    </label>
  </div>
```

with this approach stateList will keep all the checked items without an issue.

You can find the working example in [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ebvyys?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: I bonded it via `[(ngModel)]="checkboxValues[i]"` but I'm getting undefined in my array if i Consolelog it

Comment: thank you that help me a lot I was thinking way to complicated. Now It is working like a charm.